# How do I filter my DBGrid with 2 strings?

Tags: delphi

```
dm.atinlog.open;
     target :=  leftStr(postcode,4);
     dm.atinlog.filter   := 'postcode like ' + QuotedStr(target+'%') AND dm.atinlog.filter := 'autorisatie = '  + QuotedStr('klant');
     dm.atinlog.filtered := true;
     dbgrid1.visible := true;
```

This is my filter code, but this isn't working.

> [DCC Error] unPostcode.pas(95): E2010
>   Incompatible types: 'string' and
>   'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped
>   parameter'

This error is given.
What is the problem and what do I need to do to make it work?
The string "klant" is taken from a database.
It works apart from each other.
however when using filter separate only the second filter works.

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Jasper

Comment: `dm.atinlog.filter := 'postcode like ' + QuotedStr(target+'%') + ' AND autorisatie = ' + QuotedStr('klant');`

Comment: @Sertac, ah does that work like that, yes that did the trick. I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code into:

```
dm.atinlog.open;
target := leftStr(postcode,4);
dm.atinlog.filter := 'postcode like ' + QuotedStr(target+'%') 
                   + 'AND autorisatie = '+ QuotedStr('klant');
dm.atinlog.filtered := true;
dbgrid1.visible := true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Johan already gave a good answer on how to fix your filter string. But I would like to point out that if at all possible you should be using an index and SetRange instead for optimal performance.

Comment: This should have been a comment to Johan's answer, as it's not an actual answer to the question asked.

Comment: Have to disagree. Using an index/range instead of a filter is a solution of the original problem (wanting to restrict which records are visible in the grind) in it's own right.